# Embed tweets using python django + Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to embed tweets using python django and javascript.

This is my views.py currently:

```
def tweets(request):

context_dict = {}

tweets_today = Tweet.objects.order_by('-favorites')

tweets_today = tweets_today[:15]

context_dict['tweets_today'] = tweets_today

return render(request, 'summary/tweets.html', context_dict)
```

And my HTML (base.html has the twitter JS script)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
    {% for tweet in tweets_today %}

        <div class="block social-block social-twitter">
            <div id="container_{{ forloop.counter }}">

            </div>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-round btn-red"></a>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onload = (function () {

                twttr.widgets.createTweet(
                    '{{ tweet.tweet_id }}',
                    document.getElementById('container_{{ forloop.counter }}'),
                    {
                        theme: 'dark'
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>

    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

For some reason this is only embedding one tweet. Is it because of the window.onload?

Comment: Yes, you are creating multiple event handlers for the `onload` event. Your `for` loop must be inside the handler; not the other way around.